# I need to plot two graphs on one

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I'm new to the ggplot and while it seems easy, I'm having trouble to translate it to my own work.

So I've done some MDS and PCOA analysis of lizards and snakes to get a significant result. Anyway I want to plot:
MDS 2-PCOA 1 relationship and
MDS 1-PCOA 1 relationship
Considering they both have PCOA 1, this should be easy.
PCOA 1 on the x axis.

I just want points of both relationships with no lines but different coloured dots to show which relationship.

Is it also possible to have two ablines? one for each relationship?

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible as long as they have the same class for their x-axis.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  var1 = seq(2,20,2),
  var2 = c(1,2,3,4,4,3,4,5,6,2),
  var3 = c(1.5,3,4,2,5,5,6,3,1,7),
  var4 = seq(1,10,1)
)

setDT(dat)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=dat)+
  geom_point(aes(x=var1,y=var2),colour="blue")+
  geom_point(aes(x=var4,y=var3),colour="red")+
  ylab("variable")+
  ggtitle("Your title")
```

Please consider adding reprex next time since it helps clarify your question.